# How to properly use select in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I currently using [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/), and so far the code below is working `<v-select>`.

```
<v-select
    :items="order_by_opt"
    v-model="order_column"
    label="Order By"
    outlined
></v-select>

//script
data() {
    order_by_opt: ["Last Added", "Name", "Year Joined", "Age", "Date of Birth", ..etc.],
    order_column: ''
}
```

I just want to ask how can we translate the html code below to `v-select`

```
<select>
    <option value="last_added">Last Added</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    //more options here
</select>
```

In which label and value is different like for example below. If I select *Last Added*, then I should get the value *last_added*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by providing an array of objects, like [this example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#customized-item-text-and-value) in the docs. The props define which option property represents the selected value, and which is the display value.